# how to set Monitors to fixed, reduced Size

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, display-resolution, ubuntu-mate

I bought two double-FullHD (3840x2160) monitors. That will serve me well with my next, more powerful laptop.

For the time being, my Thinkpad X230 can only handle then at regular HD resolution (1920x1008), which is perfectly. When they re-connect (after working elsewhere) they are detected to be 3840px wide, and one of the two will refuse to work...

[image]

Getting all 3 to work (at 2x 1920 and the native laptop display) feels like sheer luck..  I get a lot of these:

[image]

#### So my question are like:

1) Can I somehow tell Ubuntu (Mate 16.04) about fixed resolutions instead of auto-detect (like an `/etc/fstab`-ish file)

2) Anything else to do about these `could not set the configuration for CRTC 65` errors?

3) When I am 'in luck' and all three work and are properly placed relative to each other, can I somehow save that config away (on a command line level) to (re)store later.

I appear to have an intel graphics card:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

> sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel

gets me

> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.

So I guess my drivers are up to date? (I have some refresh bugs now and then though)